# Ajax call in Java client application

Tags: java, ajax, xmlhttprequest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)

I am using the following code in Javascript to makes an Ajax call:

```
function getPersonDataFromServer() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            timeout: 30000,
            url: "SearchPerson.aspx/PersonSearch",
            data: "{ 'fNamn' : '" + stringData + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                ...
            }
        });
    }
```

I would like to do this in Java as well. Basically, I would like to write a Java client application which send this data via Ajax calls to the server.

How do I do Ajax in Java?

Comment: What you are looking for is asynchronous request in java?

Comment: Well, my problem is the actual implementation of this HTTP post request in java.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AJAX is no different from any other HTTP call. You can basically POST the same URL from Java and it shouldn't matter as far as the target server is concerned:

```
final URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/SearchPerson.aspx/PersonSearch");
final URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
urlConnection.connect();
final OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(("{\"fNamn\": \"" + stringData + "\"}").getBytes("UTF-8"));
outputStream.flush();
final InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

The code above is more or less equivalent to your jQuery AJAX call. Of course you have to replace `localhost:8080` with the actual server name.

If you need more comprehensive solution, consider [httpclient](/questions/tagged/httpclient) library and [jackson](/questions/tagged/jackson) for JSON marshalling.

## See also

- [cURL and HttpURLConnection - Post JSON Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623158)

Comment: Thank you Tomasz for your reply. But still, I have a question!
I would like to send the request to http://www.ratsit.se/BC/SearchPerson.aspx website. I have read their client part code and understood that they are sending in the following way: http://codepaste.net/u7qc1o 
Now I would like to write this ajax request in Java
I did the things that you mentioned in the answer: http://codepaste.net/1rbgpx 
but still nothing,,, Can you help me please and let me know what is wrong ?