# Send Post request with raw data, and get a file

Tags: java, json, http, post

I have a POST method in the server side, which get a JSON (as raw text) and some headers. The response is data (a file content), which send by the server to the client.

I search for a way to write the client in Java. The client sends a POST message with raw text, and some headers, and know to get the response.

All the example I saw use the `HttpsURLConnection`, but I didn't see any way to send the raw text (JSON), and get the data content.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623158/curl-and-httpurlconnection-post-json-data

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this could help ?
(Using org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2)

```
HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
    .addPart("query", new InputStreamBody(rawData, "rawData.xml"))                  
    .build();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(serverUrl);
httppost.addHeader("SomeHeader", "SomeValue");
httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
InputStream os = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

...