# How to use the following curl post command in java?

Tags: java, json, curl

i have looked into different threads on stack overflow and done some research, i am unable to run this code in java after making a http connection. 
The same command works perfectly fine in the command line

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: */*" -d "data" "http://a url"
```

I need a java code for the above curl command, i have been unable to come up with anything worthy yet

Comment: The thread does not concern itself with a java code for curl post method

Comment: So, what threads have you found? What HTTP library are you using?

Comment: https://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2012/01/17/HttpURLConnection  background.. get the WriteStream on the request and use a writer to put -d data from curl onto the Request.OutStream.  set the headers ( just Content-type probably dont need Accept  and .. should be good

Comment: @cricket_007 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623158/curl-and-httpurlconnection-post-json-data

Comment: @VasylLyashkevych is it? the thread you have mentioned has hardly anything to do with java implementation of curl commands

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone still looking

```
{String urly = "your url";
URL obj = new URL(urly);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");


con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(the data string);
wr.flush();
wr.close();

int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

BufferedReader iny = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
  String output;
  StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

  while ((output = iny.readLine()) != null) {
   response.append(output);
  }
  iny.close();

  //printing result from response
  System.out.println(response.toString());
 }
```

Comment: Would be better if there's more details on "wr.writeBytes(the data string);"